# What are the different ways to convey putting stuff into some kind of bag or cavity?

Tags: word-request, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I often find myself at lack of words when trying to convey it and I have to resort to the basic ones. One verb that I often use is "stuff". Example: I stuffed some T-shirts into the bag.

I also use the verb "squeeze". Example: I squeezed myself into the trousers.

What are some other similar verbs?

PS: These two verbs have a sense that the contents are being thrust into the bag/container/cavity because the contents are not fitting in properly. I would also wanna know about some verbs that don't have this connotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic word for putting things in bags is *pack*.  This doesn't have the connotation of not fitting in properly.

In your example *put* is also possible. Putting things into a general "cavity" is *filling* it.

And for clothing *put on*.

Simple meanings call for simple verbs.

Comment: Isn't "pop" is also used this way?

Answer (score 2):

Other words for this include *to shove* and *to cram.*